# Django Haystack - как передать динамичные данные в форму?

Tags: python, django, haystack

Как передать отсортированные продукты, в наследующий класс [FacetedSearchForm](http://pastebin.com/CcGJarLz).

На данный момент в этом классе - заранее описанные/статичные данные - благодаря которым осуществляется сортировка, по выбранному полю в выпадающем списке

Их видно на снимке экрана (Сортировать - По Релевантности,По Рейтингу, )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами данные (Словарь) которые сортируются

```
RELEVANCY = "relevancy"
TOP_RATED = "product_class_exact:Monsters"

SORT_BY_CHOICES = [
    (RELEVANCY, _("Relevancy")),
    (TOP_RATED, _("Customer rating")),
]
```

И попадают в эту форму - `choices=словарь`

```
selected_facets = forms.ChoiceField(
label=_("Sort by"), choices=SORT_BY_CHOICES,
widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

В html это выглядит следующим образом

```
 <form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
      {% include "partials/form_field.html" with field=form.selected_facets %}
 </form>
```

Непонятно каким образом - но `form.selected_facets`, берется именно из наследующего класса `FacetedSearchForm`.

И я не понимаю как следует в этот класс передать данные которые возвращает

> HayStack `SearchHandler`http://pastebin.com/ZrDrj123

На снимке их видно, это `Тип Товара` - `monsters`, а так же `Диапозон цен`.

В оригинале в форму они передаются через html, где они имеют вид простых строчных данных, которые нельзя подставить в виде `поля/Field`.

Как правильно следует сделать чтобы эти данные передавались сразу в класс `SearchForm(FacetedSearchForm)`, так чтобы их можно было записать в словарь и передать в форму `choiceForm`, `choice=data`?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы передать данные которые обработал Solr - в моем примере это  типы товаров, т.е Classic/Common), следует использовать класс Search/SearchHandler,и метод get_search_form()

```
`       def get_search_form(self, request_data, search_queryset):
        kwargs = {
            'data': request_data,
            'selected_facets': request_data.getlist("selected_facets"),
            'searchqueryset': search_queryset

        }
        return self.form_class(**kwargs)`
```

В него следует добавить, те самые результаты которые хранятся в словаре `self.results.facet_counts()`,  `kwargs = { 'facet_counts':self.results.facet_counts()}`
таким образом данные передаются в класс form_class/SearchForm, который можно представить следующим образом:

```
class SearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.facet_counts = kwargs.pop("facet_counts",[])
    super(SearchFor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    request_data = [ ("product_class_exact:Classic", _("Relevancy")),
        ("product_class_exact:T-shirt", _("Customer rating")),]
    self.fields['sort_by'] = forms.ChoiceField(
    label=_("Sort by"), choices= self.facet_counts,
widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

В оригинале он выглядит так http://pastebin.com/CcGJarLz, сам класс теперь уже переписывает оригинальный метод от Haystack `FacetedSearchForm`, но в него теперь попадают типы товаров `kwargs.pop("facet_counts",[])`, которые можно добавить в форму `choices= self.facet_counts`.

И тем самым порядок элементов - при их выборе, будет неизменным, в отличии от оригинала https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ml3K.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw58I.png .

Мой вариант решения возможно не самый красивый, и он минует оригинальный обработчик - который сделали разрабы Django(oscar) - `FacetMunger` , но темнеменее этот метод решает проблему.